# Calculating visible radius in Google Maps on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the **largest radius of the screen's visible region.**

(Before you say: Hey! Rectangulars don't have a radius! I understand that screen is rectangular (if camera is positioned in 90 degrees and not tilted), I'm talking about the radius of an imaginary circle that wraps the screen, or, the distance of the edge between the center of the screen to one of the corners of the rectangular, which is the same).

So, I understand that in a normal situation when screen is not tilted, I could take the distance between VisibleRegion.latLngbounds.southwest and the center of the screen to find the radius, but when screen is tilted, it becomes trapezoid.

Now, if the screen is an isosceled trapezoid, then I could take VisibleRegion.farLeft for example (which would be equal to farEast) and calculate the distance this way:

```
VisibleRegion vr = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    
Location center = new Location("center");
center.setLatitude(screenCenter.latitude);
center.setLongitude(screenCenter.longitude);
    
Location farVisiblePoint = new Location("farPoint");
farVisiblePoint.setLatitude(vr.farLeft.latitude);
farVisiblePoint.setLongitude(vr.farLeft.longitude);
    
float radius = center.distanceTo(farVisiblePoint);
```

My question is:

**Is there any situation with the map that the calculation above will be wrong?** Can the trapezoid not be an isosceled one?

Comment: I'm not so good at maths, but I think that if the screen is tilted and rotated it could become not isosceled. I do think than that you should check the farthest "farEast/Left" and use that one. This would give you always the biggest circle. Sorry but I can't test it, so it's just an idea

Comment: When you say "tilted", do you mean that the phone is in landscape position as opposed to portrait? How are you figuring that it becomes an isosceles trapezoid?

Comment: It is written in the docs that it's a trapezoid, but since you can only tilt upwards and dowwards then it only makes sense that the trapezoid is isoceled.
Tilted means that you can change the camera view angle of the map, instead 90 degrees it could be 45 for example. Then you are getting a trapezoid, when the far edges of the screen are the bottom of the trapozoid.